# What linq should I use for following XDocument?

Tags: linq-to-xml

I would like to create multiple different `List<string>`s or var or any other collection depending upon "MASTERKEY" element in my XDocument and would like to filter result based on RMSId.

Example in below XML If I filter on RMSId = "xyz", then I should have 3 collection of "MASTERKEY" element (USA, UK, EUR) and collection should contain "BM" element as values

For RMSId = "xyz" -- USA collection would contain {FX-SP, IR-D}

For RMSId = "xyz" -- UK collection would contain {FX-S, FX-SUK}

I am trying to use LINQ to XML, but am still learning and finding it difficult to get this running. Please advise.

Please let me know if you require any further details or seek any clarity.

```
<MSKEYS>
  <RM>
    <RMS Id="xyz">
      <Details>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>FX-SP</BM>
          <CM>123</CM>
          <RC>456</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>USA</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>NYK</Filter>
        </MDetails>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>IR-D</BM>
          <CM>789</CM>
          <RC>456</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>USA</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>CHIC</Filter>
        </MDetails>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>FX-SUK</BM>
          <CM>3453</CM>
          <RC>4353453</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>UK</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>LOND</Filter>
        </MDetails>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>FX-V</BM>
          <CM>44</CM>
          <RC>O23F</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>EUR</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>ITY</Filter>
        </MDetails>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>FX-S</BM>
          <CM>4676</CM>
          <RC>45646</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>UK</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>ENG</Filter>
        </MDetails>
      </Details>
    </RMS>
    <RMS RunId="abcd">
      <Details>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>FX-SPS</BM>
          <CM>4676</CM>
          <RC>45646</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>USA</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>NYK</Filter>
        </MDetails>
        <MDetails>
          <BM>PC</BM>
          <CM>4646</CM>
          <RC>7979</RC>
          <MASTERKEY>UK</MASTERKEY>
          <Filter>LOND</Filter>
        </MDetails>
      </Details>
    </RMS>
  </RM>
</MSKEYS>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the value for "MASTERKEY" is the key and the value is a `List<string>` containing all the "BM" elements for that key.  You can then access the values list via the key.

This is probably not the most elegant way to do it, but it will work (tested in VS 2012 on Win7 64-bit):

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
// Use XDocument.Parse(xmlString) if you have a string instead of a file

Dictionary<string, List<string> myResults = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
myResults = (from x in xDoc.Root.Elements("RM").Elements("RMS")
            where (string)x.Attribute("id") == "xyz"
            from d in x.Element("Details").Elements("MDetails")
            group d by (string)d.Element("MASTERKEY") ?? "Unknown" into g
            select new
            {
                MASTERKEY = g.Key,
                BM = g.Select(bm => (string)bm.Element("BM")).ToList()
            }).ToDictionary(k => k.MASTERKEY, v => v.BM);
```

Based on you sample XML, this will provide a dictionary with three keys (USA, UK and EUR), each with a corresponding list of the "BM" values for that key.

A couple of notes - I used `(string)` instead of `.Value` to handle cases where the element was missing or the attribute was missing - it will return null.

In the case of the key, I went one step further and used the null coalescing operator (`??`) to set a default value of "Uknown" in case the "MASTERKEY" element was not found to prevent trying to insert a null key into the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for this, but there seems some issue with "}).ToDictionary(k => k.MASTERKEY, v => v.BM);" as there is a closing round bracket ')' but opening bracket is missing.

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed now.